# Remove time zones from a string or format HTTP TIME STRING in coldfusion

Tags: string, time, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I am formatting a normal string containing `11:00 PM` or `23:00:00` using `timeFormat()` like this:

```
<cfset local.timeString = "11:00 PM">
<cfdump var="#local.timeString#">
<cfset local.newTimeString = timeFormat(local.timeString, "HH:mm:ss")>
<cfdump var="#local.newTimeString#">
```

**Output:**

> 11:00 PM 23:00:00

But in one case I came across a time string which also contains a time zone like this: `11:00 PM EDT`, so when I was trying to format this string using `timeFormat` then I was getting error which is correct.

> 11:00 PM EDT is an invalid date or time string

This type of string can be generated using [GetHttpTimeString](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_e-g_44.html).

Do I need to use something like this? It is not a correct way. Just thought this as found no other solution.

```
<cfset local.newTimeString = left(local.timeString
                                , len(local.timeString) - len(listLast(local.timeString," "))
                                )>
```

Is there any other function to format a string like this.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the built in formatting functions arent working, you could dip down to java and use the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.

```
// "hh" - 12 hour clock, "HH" - 24 hour clock
sdf = CreateObject("java","java.text.SimpleDateFormat").init("hh:mm aa zzz");
testdate = "11:00 PM EDT";
writeDump(sdf.parse(testdate));  // returns {ts '1970-01-01 22:00:00'}
```

Comment: Watch out for time zones. Using `zzz` causes the result to be adjusted based on the current time zone. That may or may not be desirable. To ignore the time zone, try `hh:mm aa` (Note, if the input uses a 12 hour clock, use lower case `hh`, not `HH`).

Comment: FYI: To avoid confusion, I updated the mask to use a 12 hour clock. Otherwise, the result is 10:00 AM (10:00) instead of 10:00 **PM** (22:00). As noted above, the reason it returns 10 o'clock, instead of 11, is because the time is being adjusted based on the default time zone of the jvm. Feel free to edit if you want to note it differently.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Regular expression to replace the timezone from the time string. This is not proper way. But you can find a solution by this method.

```
<cfset local.timeString = "11:00 PM EDT">
<cfset local.newTimeStringArray  = REMatch("((?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:[2][0-3])|(?:[0-9])):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?(?:\s?(?:am|AM|pm|PM)))",local.timeString) />
<cfdump var="#local.newTimeStringArray[1]#">
<cfset local.newTimeString = timeFormat(local.newTimeStringArray[1], "HH:mm:ss")>
<cfdump var="#local.newTimeString#">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this can be another way but by using `SimpleDateFormat` we can convert the time respective to time zones as well. Thanks :)